# Optimal solution with heuristic changed

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, heuristics

Say if I have a heuristic h(n) which is consistent (monotone).
Then is A* search f(n) = g(n) +3 ∗ h(n) gives the optimal solution?

My understanding is that it will not since 3*h(n) might be bigger than h*(n)

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm, " For the algorithm to find the actual shortest path, the heuristic function must be admissible, meaning that it never overestimates the actual cost to get to the nearest goal node." Your risk is that 3*h(n) might not be an admissible heuristic - if h(n) is reasonable, it probably won't be.

Comment: so f(n) = g(n) +3 ∗ h(n) has the potential to not be admissible right?

Comment: Yes - and then you might miss the optimal solution

Answer (score 0):

Depends if `3 * h(n)` is an admissible heuristic or not. For example, if `h(n) = 0` for every node `n`, then `3 * h(n)` will also be admissible and A* is guaranteed to find the optimal solution path when using that heuristic function.

If we define `h'(n) = 3 * h(n)`, the only thing that can be assured is that `h'(n)` is more informed than `h(n)`, but not that `h'(n)` is or is not admissible.